# install @sencha/ext-react-modern for free trial of ExtReact failed

Tags: npm, extjs, extreact

After requesting for the free trial version of ExtReact at https://www.sencha.com/products/extreact/evaluate/ an email providing a username and password was sent to my inbox.

Next, I opened my command line interface and tried to log in via command:

```
npm login --registry=https://npm.sencha.com --scope=@sencha
```

After inputting my username and password provided from the email. The output logged was this:
Logged in as username..gmail.com to scope @sencha on https://npm.sencha.com/.

Next I ran this npm command to install @sencha/ext-react-modern

```
npm install @sencha/ext-react-modern
```

Every time I try to npm install an error is thrown on the cmd line display:

> ```
> npm ERR! code E403
> npm ERR! 403 403 Forbidden - GET https://npm.sencha.com/@sencha%2fext-react-classic - unregistered users are not allowed to access package @sencha/ext-react-classic
> npm ERR! 403 In most cases, you or one of your dependencies are requesting
> npm ERR! 403 a package version that is forbidden by your security policy.
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
> npm ERR!     C:\Users\joeChicago\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-06-24T12_19_08_309Z-debug.log
> ```

Please, I will really appreciate any help you can provide. Thanks alot!

Comment: Wait a little bit (day or week), they have a terrible support. :(

Answer (score 2):

Check the link:- [ExtReact - npm ERR! 403 403 Forbidden](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63206576/extreact-npm-err-403-403-forbidden)

https://docs.sencha.com/extwebcomponents/7.0.0/guides/open_tooling_npm/npm_help.html

## Windows (Command Prompt)

1. Run del %HOMEPATH%.npmrc - removes the stored npm repository credentials. This location may be different on your system.(or manually delete this file finding it in local computer)
2. Run npm cache clean --force or rmdir /s /q %HOMEPATH%\AppData\Roaming\npm - clean the npm packages.
3. Run rmdir /s /q %HOMEPATH%\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache - clean the npm cache by removing it.
4. Run npm login --registry=https://npm.sencha.com --scope=@sencha - log back into the repository.
   Run npm install -g @sencha/ext-gen or npm install -g @sencha/ext-react-gen