# ExtReact - npm ERR! 403 403 Forbidden

Tags: reactjs, npm, extjs, extreact

I am trying to use trial version for ExtReact and using link

https://docs.sencha.com/extreact/7.2.0/guides/getting_started/creating_ext_react_app_modern.html

So, successfully got username and password and able to login as well in Step 2.

But when running Step 3: Create a React application with create-react-app and ExtReact template is not working. The below command is giving below error.

> `npx create-react-app --template @sencha/ext-react-modern ext-react-modern-demo`

## Error:

```
Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts with @sencha/cra-template-ext-react-modern...

npm ERR! code E403
npm ERR! 403 403 Forbidden - GET https://npm.sencha.com/@sencha%2fcra-template-ext-react-modern - unregistered users are not allowed to access package @sencha/cra-template-ext-react-modern
npm ERR! 403 In most cases, you or one of your dependencies are requesting
npm ERR! 403 a package version that is forbidden by your security policy.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://docs.sencha.com/extwebcomponents/7.0.0/guides/open_tooling_npm/npm_help.html

## Windows (Command Prompt)

1. Run del %HOMEPATH%.npmrc - removes the stored npm repository credentials. This location may be different on your system.(or manually delete this file finding it in local computer)
2. Run npm cache clean --force or rmdir /s /q %HOMEPATH%\AppData\Roaming\npm - clean the npm packages.
3. Run rmdir /s /q %HOMEPATH%\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache - clean the npm cache by removing it.
4. Run npm login --registry=https://npm.sencha.com --scope=@sencha - log back into the repository.
   Run npm install -g @sencha/ext-gen or npm install -g @sencha/ext-react-gen